# $.getJSON + setInterval

Tags: ajax, jsonp, setinterval, getjson

I get some data from JSONP file by below code:

```js
$.getJSON('http://static.eska.pl/m/playlist/channel-108.jsonp?callback=?' );
function jsonp(data) { 
document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = data[0].artists[0].name;
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data[0].name;
 };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>JSONP EskaRock </title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="artist"></div>
<div id="title"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works, but I need refresh data every 10 sec. I use setInterval function but console FireFox return error "ReferenceError: jsonp is not defined
(...channel-108.jsonp:1:1)". My code with setInterval:

```js
setInterval( function () {
$.getJSON('http://static.eska.pl/m/playlist/channel-108.jsonp?callback=?' );
function jsonp(data) { 
document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = data[0].artists[0].name;
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data[0].name;
};
}, 10000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>JSONP EskaRock </title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="artist"></div>
<div id="title"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the function inside the `setInterval` move it outside and it will work

```js
function jsonp(data) {
  document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = data[0].artists[0].name;
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data[0].name;
};
setInterval(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://static.eska.pl/m/playlist/channel-108.jsonp?callback=?');

}, 10000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>JSONP EskaRock </title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="artist"></div>
  <div id="title"></div>
</body>
```